# Find path of LightGBM for pyLightGBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, lightgbm

I have the latest version of `LightGBM` installed in my machine running on Windows 10. I `pip` installed `LightGBM` via `Anaconda Prompt` and it is working fine.

I found out about `pyLightGBM` and I want to use it. I installed it from this github [link](https://github.com/ArdalanM/pyLightGBM) as mentioned there. But in order to run the code with `pyLightGBM` the path for `exe` of `LightGBM` is needed as per the examples shown in the `repo`. I have searched all my drives and I am not able to file any `exe` corresponding to `LightGBM`. I found some `dll` and `py` files of it in my `Anaconda` folder.

What really is this path.? How can i find it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible, that `pip install LightGBM` isn't using any exe at all (looks like the official python-wrapper; probably more low-level wrapping and not calling-exe based). This is also indicated by [this comment](https://github.com/ArdalanM/pyLightGBM/issues/40):

> The official LightGBM package is faster as it can train from data that are in memory (no need to dump the data to disk before training on it, which I currently do for this package).

If all you need is an lightgbm.exe because pyLightGBM needs it, just go to the [release page](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/releases) of LightGBM and grab [lightgbm.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/releases/download/v2.0.10/lightgbm.exe)

(Warning: it seems it's marked as pre-release and there are no binaries for other releases; e.g. stable)

(I hope it's going to work, as in these very active ML-times: 1 year [without an update](https://github.com/ArdalanM/pyLightGBM/commits/master) sometimes already feels deprecated; but maybe there is just no reason)

Comment: I want to run `GridSearchCV` for tuning parameters of lgbm classifier. Any method for that.?

Comment: I never used lightgbm. Read their docs. But i interpreted that the sklearn-like wrapper of pyLightGBM is the sole reason you try to use it (so that sklearn's GridSearchCV works; which does according to the author).